# Is there a better approach to building things up as atoms in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

To build up a data structure I find myself doing a lot of things like:

```
(let [foo (atom [])]
  (do
    (swap! foo conj {:foo "bar"})
    (swap! foo conj {:foo "baz"}))
  @foo)

=> [{:foo "bar"} {:foo "baz"}]
```

Is this an anti-pattern?  I'm using a lot of atoms.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First off, you don't need the `do` since it is implied inside `let`. Then, for this example, plain old `->` works great (using [my favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template)):

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(defn stuff
  []
  (-> []
    (conj {:foo "bar"})
    (conj {:foo "baz"})))
  
(dotest
  (is= (stuff)
    [{:foo "bar"}
     {:foo "baz"}])
```

Another option is to user `reduce`:

```
(defn save-odds
  [accum arg]
  (if (odd? arg)
    (conj accum arg)
    accum))

<snip>

  (is= (reduce save-odds
         []
         (range 6))
    [1 3 5]))
```

Having said that, there is nothing wrong IMHO with using an atom as an accumulator.  It is simple & straightforward. And, if the "nasty" mutation of the atom never leaks outside of your function, it cannot cause any complexity in the rest of the program.

> "If mutation occurs and no outside function is affected, does
> it really matter?"

After all, `reduce` and friends also use mutation internally, and they are excellent examples of "functional" programming.  That is, they are ***pure functions*** (have referential transparency), and cause no side effects.

Comment: Oh yeah! Thrilled to see the arrow operator works like this. Because it's so much more readable this way, among other things!

Comment: The threading macros `->` and `->>` are usually pronounced "thread-first" and "thread-last", respectively.

Comment: I appreciate the clarification on mutation... it helps me understand when mutations are better. Not too clear still on `referential transparency`.

Comment: It means that the function will always produce the same result for a given set of inputs (i.e. it is a "pure function" w/o side effects). Thus, you can replace a function call like `(+ 2 3)` with the value `5`.

Comment: OK... gotcha. Perusing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency now.

Answer (score 6):

No need for an `atom` here. You can use immutable data structures:

```clj
(-> []
    (conj {:foo "bar"})
    (conj {:foo "baz"}))
;;=> [{:foo "bar"} {:foo "baz"}]
```

For folks coming from OOP or imperative languages, this is probably the hardest shift: avoiding mutability.

Comment: Gee, that answer looks familiar!

Comment: On the avoiding mutability front... I'm finding myself using a zillion atoms in cljs projects and modifying them everywhere with swap! and reset! I am guessing I'm not quite on the right track with this.

Comment: Most cljs apps have a single atom containing their "state".

Comment: That's what I've been suspecting. I avoid that because I'm clumsy at accessing and mutating that single atom  which becomes more complex than a bunch of simple atoms. However, you are all helping over that hump.